# Outlook recipient receiving winmail.dat file

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encryption

I am sending mail to a recipient that is using Outlook.

Normally Outlook opens winmail.dat files automatically. However, this is not happening. Instead he is receiving the winmail.dat file as an attachment. This is probably happening because the email was sent encrypted.

How can he open the ATTACHED winmail.dat file using Outlook?

Note: I have changed settings so that I am sending in plain text format (see below) and he STILL cannot open it (it is still being sent in winmail.dat) so those settings are not working.

[image]

Comment: Ensure you're not sending it in RTF format.

Comment: I know how to avoid sending a Winmail.dat file. That is not my question. My question is how can he open a winmail.dat file using Outlook.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I think so, I am still in the process of sending test emails back and forth.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT No, I changed settings to send as plain text and it is still sending the winmail.dat file.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous yeah maybe REOPEN my frickin question. Because its a DUPLICATE, why don't you go check the DUPLICATE question because that is where all the answers are.

Comment: Tyler - I removed the other answer I had on this with other detail and steps... Can you see my deleted answer still below the one I know you can see for sure. I wasn't sure if any of that helped. I'm not sure why it's be duplicate if it hasn't resolved your problem other than people just voting for it in review. I will undelete my other answer if you want to see it again.

Answer (score 2):

> How can he open the ATTACHED winmail.dat file using Outlook?

As listed in this [Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278061), "**The data in a winmail.dat file is not usable**"

> ### [Email received from a sender using Outlook includes a Winmail.dat attachment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278061)
>
> **CAUSE**
>
> The Winmail.dat file is used to preserve Rich Text formatting. Outlook
>   uses it when sending a Rich Text-formatted message. During transport,
>   the content of the message may be changed, preventing the receiving
>   client from being able to read the formatting instructions. In other
>   cases, the receiving client does not use or recognize the winmail.dat
>   file.
>
> **RESOLUTION**
>
> The data in a winmail.dat file is not usable. To resolve this issue,
>   ask the sender to re-send the message in plain text format. The
>   following methods can be used by sender to prevent sending Rich Text
>   messages encapsulated in the Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format
>   (TNEF).
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278061)</sub>